# how to start apache tomcat on apache-cloudstack management server

Tags: tomcat, apache-cloudstack

i am trying to install cloudstack. and was configuring management server. setup is done but when try to start cloud management service it failed. and error was cloudsatck-management tomcat servelet not running.

Comment: Which version of cloudstack are you running on what OS? Also, can we see the error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed `tomcat6` properly.

```
#yum install tomcat6
```